# Фильтр Google data studio по URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-data-studio

Мне нужно отправить общую статистику партнерам, но так что б они видели только статистику своей компании. Потратил кучу дней, но не нашел ответа, в русском сегменте совсем ничего нет, в английском не нашел (или не понял) как это сделать. Партнеров около 400, для каждого делать индивидуально очень долго, можно ли сделать фильтр по ссылке или идентификатор по почте компании?

Помогите мне и другим, буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по моему опыту, использование ссылок для отчетов губительно для организации и автоматизации. Невероятно сложно контроллировать 50-100 отчетов, не говорю о 4Х.

В этом случае я предпочитаю два решения, оба из которых сильно коррелируют между собой по качеству и простоте обслуживания. Оба они **не подразумевают использование фильтров**.

### I. Способ "разделения источников"

Очень часто Таблиц Гугл достаточно для реализации источника данных. Достаточно решить вопрос разделения/распространения данных между Таблицами каждого партнера и предоставить всем им один шаблон для реализации отчета DS. Им нужно только самостоятельно подключить источник данных.

Очевидный недостаток в том, что раскидать данные между 400 Таблицами - это дело не одной секунды. Надо будет немного постараться.

### II. Способ "частный коннектор"

На базе DS и Apps Script возможно реализовать простейший коннектор, который и раздавать своим партненам с нужными ключами доступа.

Очевидный недостаток этого способа в необходимости освоения технологии хотя бы на уровне обычного коннектора DS.

При всей необычности первого способа он часто бывает очень удобным, понятным и, главное, гибким. Не все [пользователи], далеко не все, готовы смортеть в веселые картинки DS/Power BI, находя сухие нормализованные Таблицы более надежным источником информации для собственных отчетов тех же DS/Power BI.

Надеюсь, что это тот ответ принесет какую-то ясность.